# What are the current steps to write a Google Tasks or Drive App?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

After looking thru lots of pages (mostly contradict) I'm not able to write a simple Android app that does connect to Google with OAuth2:

I started with this page:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android#account

I did download the current libs and had to experience lots of deprecated or missing functions:

- GoogleAccountManager is deprecated
- HttpTransport, AndroidHttp, AccessProtectedResource, GoogleAccessProtectedResource, JacksonFactory will not be found in the current libs
- Generation of CLIENT_ID thru Developer Console worked
- Generation of SECRET did not work for Mobile App but is required

What is the most current description? What's the most current demo?

Just in case - here's what I did so far. None of the methods in processTokenReceived are part of the libs:

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {

    private static final String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive";
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";

    private AccountManager accountManager;
    private Account[] accounts;
    private String authName;
    private String authToken;

    @Override
    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialogInterface, final int item) {

        processAccountSelected(accounts[item]);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);

        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

        accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

        if (accounts == null || accounts.length == 0) {
            // TODO
        } else if (accounts.length == 1) {
            processAccountSelected(accounts[0]);
        } else if (accounts.length > 1) {
            showDialog(MyConstants.DIALOG_ACCOUNTCHOSER);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(final int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case MyConstants.DIALOG_ACCOUNTCHOSER:
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                String[] names = new String[accounts.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
                    names[i] = accounts[i].name;
                }

                alertDialogBuilder.setItems(names, this);
                alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Select a Google account");
                return alertDialogBuilder.create();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void processAccountSelected(final Account account) {
        if (account != null) {
            authName = account.name.toString();
            if (!Tools.isEmpty(authName)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, authName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                accountManager.getAuthToken(account, AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, null, this,
                        new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

                            public void run(final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                                try {
                                    authToken = future.getResult().getString(
                                            AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                                    processTokenReceived();
                                } catch (OperationCanceledException exception) {
                                    // TODO
                                } catch (Exception exception) {
                                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), exception.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        }, null);
            }
        }
    }

    private void processTokenReceived() {
        if (!Tools.isEmpty(authToken)) {
            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            AccessProtectedResource accessProtectedResource = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(
                    accessToken);
            Tasks service = new Tasks(transport, accessProtectedResource, new JacksonFactory());
            service.accessKey = CLIENT_ID;
            service.setApplicationName("Google-DriveSample/1.0");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recent example for using `AccountManager` in combination with a [google-api-services library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs) is the [updated Tasks API example](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java?repo=samples).[`GoogleAccountManager`](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.11.0-beta/index.html?com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android/accounts/GoogleAccountManager.html) was e.g. just moved to [another package](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.11.0-beta/index.html?com/google/api/client/googleapis/extensions/android2/auth/GoogleAccountManager.html).

If you are not using a build manager like Maven that resolves missing dependencies for you, you of course have to include the [google-api-java-client libraries](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list) manually, which provide `HttpTransport`, etc.

For using `AccountManager` it is sufficient to use the Simple API Access key, that is provided in the API console. The part with a certificate fingerprint will only be relevant once [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/google-play-services/) will be available.

Comment: Moving packages in a beta? Ok, seems that I better wait until next year ;-) Anyway, accepted the answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The Google Play Services are now available